# How to fix 'UnicodeDecodeError:'?

Tags: python, json, sqlite, decode

I'm trying to create a chatbot and whenever I try running my code I get this,

**line 107, in 
    for row in f:
  File "/Users/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 102: ordinal not in range(128)**

I was going to try to add,

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

However I was told that **setdefaultencoding** is not safe to use, so I never got around to trying this.

Below is my code,

```
import sqlite3
import json
from datetime import datetime

timeframe = '2015-01'
sql_transaction = []

connection = sqlite3.connect('/Users/usr/Desktop/fileName/RC_{}'.format(timeframe))
c = connection.cursor()


def create_table():
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent_reply
    (parent_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, comment_id TEXT UNIQUE, parent TEXT,
     comment TEXT, subreddit TEXT, unix INT, score INT)""")


def format_data(data):
    data = data.replace("\n", " newlinechar ").replace("\r", " newlinechar ").replace('"', "'")
    return data


def find_existing_score(pid):
    try:
        sql = "SELECT score FROM parent_reply WHERE parent_id = '{}' LIMIT 1".format(pid)
        c.execute(sql)
        result = c.fetchon()
        if result != None:
            return result[0]
        else:
            return False
    except Exception as e:
        # print("find_parent", e)
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_table()
    row_counter = 0
    paired_rows = 0


    with open("/Users/usr/Desktop/fileName/RC_{}".format(timeframe), buffering=1000) as f:
        for row in f:
            row_counter += 1
            row = json.loads(row)
            parent_id = row['parent_id']
            body = format_data(row['body'])
            created_utc = row['created_utc']
            score = row['score']
            subreddit = row['subreddit']
            comment_id = row['name']
            parent_data = find_parent(parent_id)

            if score >= 2:
                if acceptable(body):
                    existing_comment_score = find_existing_score(parent_id)
                    if existing_comment_score:
                        if score > existing_comment_score:
                            sql_insert_replace_comment(comment_id, parent_id, parent_data, body, subreddit, created_utc, score)

                    else:
                        if parent_data:
                            sql_insert_has_parent(comment_id, parent_id, parent_data, body, subreddit, created_utc, score)
                            paired_rows += 1
                        else:
                            sql_insert_no_parent(comment_id, parent_id, body, subreddit, created_utc, score)
            if row_counter % 100000 == 0:
                print("Total rows read: {}, Paired rows: {}, Time: {}".format(row_counter, paired_rows, str(datetime.now())))
```

The RC_2015-01 is extracted from a zip file named RC_2015-01.bz2. I'm not sure if this is an issue.

Comment: Please match line 26 from your error message to the code you posted. The code above suggests it's this line: `c.execute(sql)` which doesn't seem right.

Comment: "ordinal not in range(128)" imo usually mean the input file you're trying to decode isn't saved in 8 bits, which means utf-8 probably will fail as well. Try replacing ascii_decode (whatever that actually do) to some function that decodes in utf-16 or utf-32.

Comment: @davejagoda ```c.execute(sql)``` is line 26

Comment: Reading more closely, I think this is the line number: `line 107, in for row in f:`. Can you give us the complete traceback? is RC_2015-01 a text file?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

```
timeframe = '2015-01'
sql_transaction = []

connection = sqlite3.connect('/Users/usr/Desktop/fileName/RC_{}.db'.format(timeframe))
c = connection.cursor()
```

The issue was that it would create a database that wasn't a database and would have the same name as the file it was trying to decode. By adding **.db** the file becomes a database and gets a different name.